# How can I use the "timestamps" within the json files to set the DataFrame from day X to day Y and not from year X to year Y?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I would like to do some text analysis on different json files. These files are named like e.g. "2017.json" or "2018.json".

They contain many texts with one timestamp each. (e.g. "timestamp": "2019-01-31T19:15:00",)

The basic structure of pandas is the so-called DataFrame. I first created a DataFrame and then append the data for the individual years (here only one year) to it. This ensures that the data is all available in the same structure.

Now I can only create the DataFrame with the individual years. Is it possible to use the timestamp within the files to create the DataFrame e.g. from day x to day y?

```py
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame()

#json file 2017
for year in range (2017,2018):
    data = pd.concat([data, pd.read_json("%d.json" % year, orient="records")], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: I think you can easily filter the `data` frame by specifiying the data range like this: `dataFiltered = data[(data['date'] > '2019-03-01') & (data['date'] <= '2019-06-10')]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the specific range, you can filter the data frame for those specific dates, and get the new data frame out of it.

```
filtered_df = df[(df['date'] > 'from date') & (df['date'] < 'to date')]
```

Then you can save the filtered_df mentioning the from & to range in the filename

Comment: I have to take "timestamp" instead of "date", but it works! :) thank you